# Visual Basic MsgBox vbYesNo Doesn't accept when the 'No' button is clicked

Tags: vb.net

I have a MsgBox in my VB.NET Form's program with a vbYesNo parameter attached. Whenever the messagebox shows, I see the yes and no buttons, however no matter which button I click, I always get the same result.

Here's my code:

```
MsgBox("Here's 2 options...", vbYesNo)
If vbYes Then
    MsgBox("You clicked yes")
Else
    MsgBox("You clicked no")
End If
```

I've also tried the same as above where the If statement is:

```
If vbYes Then
    MsgBox("You clicked yes")
ElseIf vbNo Then
    MsgBox("You clicked no")
End If
```

When I click Yes, or No on the Messagee Box, I always get whatever's in:

```
If vbYes Then
    MsgBox("You clicked yes")
```

I'm relatively new to Visual Basic forms so I'm sorry if this is a simple rookie mistake. I hope this info is enough to go on.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You need to get the response of the `MsgBox`. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/msgbox-function#example) example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your issue is that you are not capturing the value returned by the MsgBox, you should try something like this:

```
   Dim a As MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("Here's 2 options...", vbYesNo)
    If a = vbYes Then
        MsgBox("You clicked yes")
    Else
        MsgBox("You clicked no")
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

**Option 1**:

```
If MessageBox.Show("Here's 2 options", "Select Option", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.Yes Then
    MessageBox.Show("You clicked yes", "Result")
Else
    MessageBox.Show("You clicked no", "Result")
End If
```

**Option 2**:

```
If MsgBox("Here's 2 options", vbYesNo, "Select option") = vbYes Then
    MsgBox("You clicked yes", vbOKOnly, "Result")
Else
    MsgBox("You clicked no", vbOKOnly, "Result")
End If
```